# To generate push notification based on user current device location in android

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, location

I am able to get push notification from server but my app should receive push notification when user device location change in latitude and longitude.

**Case 1:**

I have to send device latitude and longitude values to server and it has to send push notification whenever user device current location change.(Moves from Place A to Place B  to get notification) even if the app is running in background,app needs to configure with system OS to get push.

**Case 2:**

Iam able to move to activity while clicking on push notification but i need like if i have received two push notification from server clicking on first notification it has to take FirstActivity and clicking on second push notification take to secondActivity.
How to identify which push notification is to redirect to activity.

code to show push notification in **GCMNotificationIntentService:**

```
private void createNotification(String msg){
    Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.offer, "GCM Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION_ID,notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Message From GCM", msg, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    NOTIFICATION_ID = NOTIFICATION_ID + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1.You need to create **service** which will be runing in background. Also you need somehow send notification to the telephone from your server and handle it. But it could be achived without server, you could just listen to **LocationListener.OnLocationChanged**

2.According to second question you can prepare right **Intent** before displaying notification, assign it to the notification, and after clicking it, you will be moved directly to this activity.

```
Intent intent = //prepare your intent
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentIntent(contentIntent);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

Comment: Thanks @maciej for your response if you dont mind could you please share some code to move to different activities for push notifications as well for case 1 (service calling location updates)